# How can I add and calculate a column's value in R

Tags: r

This is the first part of my code:

```
BSum=0.0 
mydata = NULL 
while(BSum < 5) 
{ 
A=(rpois (1, lambda=1)) 
y=runif(A,0,1) 
B1 = length(which(y<=0.5)) 
BSum = BSum + B1 
C = A - B1 
mydata=rbind(mydata,c("A"=A,"B"=B1,"C"=C)) 
}
```

I need 3 more columns here. For column D(row x) I would generate as many random nos. (between 0 and 1) as is the value in Column B(row x). Then I see how many of those random nos. are less than or equal to 0.1. I put the total count of these in Column D. The remainder (B-D) becomes column F. I generate another column E that will get populated the same same way D was generated from B. The remainder again gets added to what had accumulated in Column F.

Comment: I'm presuming that this is related to use with the `data.table` package and that you have already loaded the `data.table` package...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:=` is from the **data.table** package. As you don't have this loaded, either your object isn't a `data.table` object or it is but you don't say and the package was not loaded.

If the former (your object is a data frame, not a `data.table`) then you want `cbind()`. As in:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(A = runif(10))
cbind(df, list(B = runif(10), C = letters[1:10]))

> cbind(df, list(B = runif(10), C = letters[1:10]))
            A         B C
1  0.26550866 0.2059746 a
2  0.37212390 0.1765568 b
3  0.57285336 0.6870228 c
4  0.90820779 0.3841037 d
5  0.20168193 0.7698414 e
6  0.89838968 0.4976992 f
7  0.94467527 0.7176185 g
8  0.66079779 0.9919061 h
9  0.62911404 0.3800352 i
10 0.06178627 0.7774452 j
```

For your particular problem, try:

```
myfun <- function(z) {
  ret1 <- apply(z, 1, function(x) sum(runif(x) <= 0.1))
  ret2 <- z[,1] - ret1
  cbind(z, B = ret1, C = ret2)
}

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(A = rpois(10, 2))
myfun(df)


> myfun(df)
   A B C
1  1 0 1
2  1 0 1
3  2 0 2
4  4 0 4
5  1 0 1
6  4 0 4
7  4 1 3
8  2 0 2
9  2 0 2
10 0 0 0
```

You could make this more efficient, say by not doing each row individually, but it'd involve more coding.

#### Updated

If I understand your update (and I might not as I already showed you how to do those steps, though not in the same configuration as you now want), then I think this is what you wanted. Note that how you create `E` is a little ambiguous. I took you literally and just did exactly the same as for `D`.

```
set.seed(2)
BSum <- 0.0
mydata <- NULL
while(BSum < 5) { 
  A <- rpois(1, lambda = 1)  
  B1 <- sum(runif(A, 0, 1) <= 0.5)
  BSum <- BSum + B1 
  C <- A - B1 
  D <- sum(runif(B1) <= 0.1)
  F <- B1 - D
  E <- sum(runif(B1) <= 0.1)
  F <- F + (D - E)
  mydata <- rbind(mydata, c(A = A, B = B1, C = C, D = D, E = E, F = F)) 
}
```

With that seed I get

```
R> mydata
     A B C D E F
[1,] 0 0 0 0 0 0
[2,] 1 0 1 0 0 0
[3,] 0 0 0 0 0 0
[4,] 3 1 2 0 0 1
[5,] 1 1 0 0 0 1
[6,] 1 0 1 0 0 0
[7,] 3 3 0 0 0 3
```

Comment: @user3185283 Edit your question with this new info, and I'll take a look.

Comment: Gavin, please let me know if I should provide you any further information. And btw, thanks for helping :)

Comment: @user3185283 thanks, but I can't make head nor tail of this from the comments. Please edit your question and include this infomation there. then I'll take a look.

Comment: @user3185283 is that what you wanted?

Comment: @user3185283 I don't mean to be rude, but did you read my updated answer? There *are* three more columns as per your textual description. So instead of bleating and shouting either tell me what you want if what I've just added is not enough. This isn't your own personal support line you know!

Comment: Sir, I am new to this site and was finding it a little difficult to handle. Plus, as would have been obvious to you by now, I am in the very nascent stages of learning R.I had not understood your last comment and tried to explain again. I did not realize that the answer had been updated. Apologies again for having offended you. I do not think of this line has being my personal support and I am grateful to you for having assisted me.

Comment: Row 7 in the answer you generated should ideally have only 3 in column F as none of it percolated down to D and E (from B and from D respectively). Also, did it just so happened that none of the values from B percolated down to D and E? I mean had we given 0.9 instead of 0.1 would there have been higher chances of getting values in D from B and then from D to E?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your comments, what does "percolate down to D and E" mean? My updated code does *exactly* what you said in words in the edited question. `D` contains a random sample of `B1` uniforms between 0 and 1 (`B1` because that is column `B` according to your code). The probability that any of these are <= 0.1 is much lower than <= 0.9. I do follow you about `F` though. It is being summed regardless. I'll fix that. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: I think I follow now, although when you say "The remainder again gets added to what had accumulated in Column F", what do you mean be "remainder", of what? From your comment I presume you mean add `E` to the values in `F` in this current iteration. In other words, `F <- (B1-D) + E`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: thank you very much! Its really embarassing that i am going on troubling you both with regards to my limitations in R as well as being able to handle the site (im still sirry for having upset you yesterday). But thanks alot once again for being so patient.

Comment: I would get 2 sets of remainders: D comes from B based on what probability i specify( like you cleared out in your comment), B-D goes to F. Next, E is generated from D (using the user defined probability) D -E goes to F again. So ideally E +F will always add up to B

Comment: Ah, you don't mention this explicitly. I guess what you wrote is OK for you as you understand what you want to have happen, but that was totally lost on me. OK, final try... Give me a minute to edit the Answer...

Comment: Thats exactly what i wanted! Thank you very much sir!

Comment: @user3185283 You are welcome. Next time, try to be a little more explicit about what you want. It does help and you may solve your problem yourself, just be writing a good question out.

Comment: @Gavin.next time, I surely will.